# Cypres - mochawesome reports - reportDir

Tags: javascript, report, cypress, mochawesome

I am trying to implement dynamic path to mochawesome reports for different browsers
e.g for example, for chrome it is supposed to be cypress/reports/chrome/mocha

This is my **cypress.json** configuration for reporter

```
 "reporter": "cypress-multi-reporters",
"reporterOptions": {
    "reporterEnabled": "mochawesome",
    "mochawesomeReporterOptions": {
        "quiet": true,
        "overwrite": false,
        "html": false,
        "json": true

    }
},
```

And this is how I'm trying to run tests with custom reporterDir

```
"cypress run --spec cypress\\integration\\filter\\*.js --browser chrome --headless --config-file config.json --config videosFolder=cypress\\videos\\chrome downloadsFolder=cypress\\downloads\\chrome --reporter mochawesome --reporter-options reportDir=cypress/reports/chrome/mocha"
```

but it doesnt work. Reports are saved under path from cypress.json. I tried different syntax many times but I just can't make it work. I need it because my tests will be launched on many browsers and I want to make reports directory well organised.

Comment: Have you tried making the directory as a cypress environment variable in cypress.env.json?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up with https://www.npmjs.com/package/@bahmutov/cypress-extends - plugin responsible for extending cypress configuration file so I have created one for each browser with its own path for reports, videos and downloads and now I'm launching scripts like that `"cypress run --spec cypress\\integration\\*.js --browser chrome --config-file config_BROWSER.json"`. I have also deleted multi-reporters plugins because I realized I don't need it.

Cypress.json

```
"reporter": "mochawesome",
  "reporterOptions": {
    
          "quiet": true,
          "overwrite": false,
          "html": false,
          "json": true,
  }
```

config_chrome.json

```
{
"extends": "./cypress.json",

"reporter": "mochawesome",
"reporterOptions": {
        "reportDir": "cypress/reports/chrome/mocha"   
    },

"videosFolder": "cypress/videos/chrome",
"downloadsFolder": "cypress/downloads/chrome"}
```

and then config_edge.json and config_firefox.json - similar to chrome but with different paths

Comment: Great that you found a solution. Could you also provide an example of the resulting cypress.json config files? Thanks

Comment: Sure thing, but tomorrow because today I don't have access to it.